# kotlin realm demo canot be run

Tags: realm, kotlin

kotlin version 1.0.0,realm version 0.88.0-SNAPSHOT
I download realm kotlin demo ,and run
if code like this:

```
    var person = Person()
    person.id = 1
    person.name = "Young Person"
    person.age = 14
    realm.beginTransaction()
    realm.copyToRealm(person)
    realm.commitTransaction()
```

throw Exception: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: io.realm.examples.kotlin.model.Person cannot be cast to io.realm.PersonRealmProxyInterface

else  I change code like this:

```
    realm.beginTransaction()
    // Add a person
    var person = realm.createObject(Person::class.java)
    person.id = 1
    person.name = "Young Person"
    person.age = 14
    // When the transaction is committed, all changes a synced to disk.
    realm.commitTransaction()
```

then realm insert a data but person.name ,id,age is empty value or 0;

how to solve it

Comment: After clone the `realm-java` project, try run `/gradlew installRealmJava` in the project root dir first. Then build the example.

Comment: You do not show your Person class, would be nice to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Realm 0.88.0-SNAPSHOT you have to use their Gradle Plugin as well.  If you Google this exception (`realm java.lang.ClassCastException ProxyInterface`) you will find this [Github Issue - 2353](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2353) which says:

> We just merged our byte code weaver into master, and it sounds like it isn't being triggered in your case. Note that from 0.88.0-SNAPSHOT you have to use our Gradle plugin: https://realm.io/news/android-installation-change/

Previously you would install Realm like:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:<version>'
}
```

Now you must install it to also include the Gradle plugin:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:<version>"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

So that byte code weaving is turned on.  Without this, you receive an error exactly like your first use case (which was correct code, but for the snapshot release you chose to use, you also needed this extra step of the Gradle plugin).  There are other important notes in the link above, along with the release notes for changes in recent versions of Realm.

Comment: i add `classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:<version>"` and  `apply plugin: 'realm-android'`  but error like `Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: io/realm/annotations/Ignore.class`  sometime is Index.class, i found that :[link](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1545
) and [link](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1807) but canot solve it ,help,thx

Comment: Can you start a new question, and you will need to include your list of dependencies, along with the output of gradle dependencies command because it will show what else is bringing in another copy of Realm library.  It cannot be solved in comments here.